# 64-bit VM on 32 bit Windows XP

Tags: vmware, vmware-player

When I try to run a 64-bit VM on 32 bit Windows XP, I get the following message:

> You have configured this virtual
>   machine to use a 64-bit guest
>   operating system.  However, 64-bit
>   operation is not possible. This host
>   does not support VT.

I have activated VP, VMM compatibility on my host but I still have the error.

Any idea on what might be going wrong?

Comment: This belongs on ServerFault or SuperUser however you may want to look at this post http://superuser.com/questions/156859/vmware-this-host-doesnt-support-vt-can-not-play-64bit-vm-due-to-lack-of-vt-fla

Answer (score 0):

In that case your processor doesn't support [Intel VT-x](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization#Intel_virtualization_.28VT-x.29), even though you have enabled hardware virtualization in your bios your host doesn't support VT-x.

To confirm, figure out what model of processor you have and then check the table on Wikipedia, e.g. [List of Intel Core 2 microprocessors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Core_2_microprocessors). Not all Intel processors support VT-x as they use this technology as part of their market segmentation.

Answer (score 0):

YES - you can do it!
if:
 - your processor supports hardware virtualization and it is switched on
 - and your virtual machine software supports it

I run the 64 bit versions of Vista and Windows 7 on my Vista 32bit machine using VMWare Workstation and it works just fine (aside from being a little slow).
The VMWare Player, which is free, should be able to do this as well.
MS Virtual PC cannot.

First check to see if your processor supports hardware virtualization and that its turned on (many systems come with it turned off by default) by going to GRC and downloading a little freeware app called SecurAble
     http://www.grc.com/securable.htm

If your system has hardware virtualization but it is turned off - the switch is probably located in the bios settings. So you'll have to reboot your system, go into the bios and look for the entry that controls whether its turned on or off.
On my HP laptop its under the group of settings on the far right menu option. Sorry I don't remember what the menu item is called.

Answer (score -1):

You can not run a 64-bit program in a 32-bit operating system, whether your cpu is 64-bit or not.
VT is only supported by 64-bit processors, so a PC without a 64-bit processor can not run a 64-bit virtual machine in 32-bit XP.
That is really what the error says.

Comment: This is not true for the question at hand.  It is possible to run a 64bit OS in a Virtual Machine when the Host Machine is only running a 32bit OS.  The problem is the Processor/System need to be able to support Virtualization Technology.